# How do I make HTML run my JavaScript for as long as I please?

Tags: javascript

I want my HTML code to run my JS code forever or for a very long time at least. How can I accomplish this?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
<title>2D Sierpinski Gasket</title>
<script language ="JavaScript" src ="RandomCircle">
</script>

<script language ="JavaScript" src ="webgl-utils.js"></script> 
<script language ="JavaScript" src ="InitShaders.js"></script> 
<script language ="JavaScript" src ="MV.js"></script> 
<script>
 var mar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
</script>

<script language ="JavaScript" src ="RandomCircle.js"></script>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">        
attribute vec4 vPosition;

void
main()
{
    gl_PointSize = 1.0;
    gl_Position = vPosition;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

void
main()  
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>


  <body>


    <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
      <!-- The following message is displayed if the browser doesn't support HTML5 -->
      Sorry; your web browser does not support HTML5's canvas element
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I tried using var mar as a setInterval, but I don't quite understand it unfortunately.

Here's the Js.

```
var canvas;
var gl;
var x = Math.random(); 
var y = Math.random();
var center  = vec2(x, y);

var points = [];

var numCirclePoints = 30;
var radius = 0.5;       


window.onload = function init() {
var myFunction = function() {};
x = Math.random(); 
y = Math.random(); 
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );


    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    points.push( center );
    createCirclePoints( center, radius, numCirclePoints );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    var myFunction = function() {
    init(); 

    };


    render();
}


// Create the points of the circle
function createCirclePoints( cent, rad, k )
{
    var dAngle = 2*Math.PI/k;
    for( i=k; i>=0; i-- ) {
        a = i*dAngle;

        var p = vec2( rad*Math.sin(a) + cent[0], rad*Math.cos(a) + cent[1] );
        points.push(p);
    }
}

function render() {

    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    // Draw circle using Triangle Fan
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, numCirclePoints+2 );

    window.requestAnimFrame(render);
    init();
}
```

I only wish for the JS to repeat itself in the HTML, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you keep calling your init() function in your render? And from the looks of it your render function should be getting called continuously. And what is `myTimer`?

Answer (score 5):

> As you can see I tried using var mar as a setInterval, but I don't quite understand it unfortunately.

You can definitely use this. Just replace 3000 with how often you want the code to run.

```
setInterval(function(){
    // Your repeating code here
), 3000 };
```

If that doesn't work, please check your console, and add some console.logs, as well as explaining what the script does, to help us understand.

Comment: So in my case, I want to run the JS file as often as I please, should I then go for 
setInterval(function(){
    // Your repeating code here
), 3000 }; in the HTML or in the JS file?

Comment: Put all of the javascript in the HTML file into the javascript file and put it inside of the part that says `// Your repeating code here`. If for some reason that doesn't work, try wrapping both the javascript in the html and the javascript in the js file with `setInterval`